# linux extract only a string starts with a special string and ends with the first occurrence of comma

Tags: regex, grep

I have a log file contains some information like below

```
"variable1=XXX, emotionType=sad, sentimentType=negative..."
```

What I want is to grep only the matched string, the string starts with emotionType and ends with the first occurrence of comma.
E.g.

```
emotionType=sad
emotionType=joy
...
```

What I have tried is

```
grep -e "/^emotionType.*,/" file.log -o
```

but I got nothing. Anyone can tell me what should I do?

Comment: Is your source a file, stream from stdin or a variable? Are the quotation marks part of the source?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```sh
grep -o "emotionType[^,]*" file.log
```

Note:

- Remove `^` or replace with `\<`, starting word boundary construct if your matches are not located at the beginning of each line
- Remove the `/` chars on both ends of the regex since `grep` does not use regex delimiters (like `sed`)
- `[^,]` is a *negated* bracket expression that matches any char other than a comma
- `*` is a POSIX BRE quantifier that matches zero or more occurrences.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/dkaLSP):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="variable1=XXX, emotionType=sad, sentimentType=negative, emotionType=happy"
grep -o "emotionType=[^,]*" <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
emotionType=sad
emotionType=happy
```

Comment: hi @Wiktor Stribizew, thank you for reply. I have tried your code but still got nothing

Comment: @Mengyang `^` requires the match to appear at the start of a line, if they are not there, remove `^` or replace with `\<`, a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` you could try following program. Simple explanation would be using `awk`'s `match` function capability and using regex to match string emotionType till next occurrence of `,` and printing all the matches in `awk` program.

```
var="variable1=XXX, emotionType=sad, sentimentType=negative, emotionType=happy"
```

Where `var` is a shell variable.

```
echo "$var" | 
awk '{while(match($0,/emotionType=[^,]*/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Or in GNU `awk` using `RS` variable try following `awk` program.

```
echo "$var" | awk -v RS='emotionType=[^,]*' 'RT{sub(/\n+$/,"",RT);print RT}'
```